# i am getting this Error: "The report definition is not valid" while creating a report using the Report Wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

i am getting this error when i'm trying to create a report using the Report Wizard.

The report definition is not valid.  Details: The element 'TableCells' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition:TableCell'.  F:\mysite\myReport.rdlc

please help me with this guys!

my code looks something like this

```
<Table Name="table1">
<Top>0.5in</Top>
<Style />
<Header>
  <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
  <TableRows>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCells></TableCells>
      <Height>0in</Height>
    </TableRow>
  </TableRows>
</Header>
<Details>
  <TableRows>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCells></TableCells>
      <Height>0in</Height>
    </TableRow>
  </TableRows>
</Details>
<TableColumns />
<DataSetName>reportDataSet_DataTable1</DataSetName>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<TableCells></TableCells>` elements must contain at least one `<TableCell>`.

Does your dataset contain any columns?